# How to retrieve data from sqlite database by category

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table contain 5 columns id,product_category,product_price,product_name,product_quantity.

i want to retrieve data grouped according to category.
how to query this data??

Comment: Are you sure that you want GROUP, this would result in all rows having the same category being represented by just one row. You may want to ORDER BY category, This would return the rows in order of the category but the rows returned will be on a 1 for 1 basis. Normally you would use some form of count/sum when using group,

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select only distinct categories -

```
Select * from table_name group by product_category;
```

If you want your categories to repeat then -

```
Select * from table_name order by product_category;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> Select id,product_category,product_price,product_name,product_quantity from table_name GROUP BY product_category

or

> Select * from table_name GROUP BY product_category

or sqlite format

> Select * from " + YOUR_TABLE_NAME + "  group by " + KEY_PRODUCT_CATEGORY + "

I thing It will help u.....